# Interpolating 3d angles (in Garry's Mod)

Tags: math, 3d, angle, garrys-mod

I'm trying to interpolate angles in [*Expression 2*](http://wiki.wiremod.com/wiki/Expression_2), as such:

```php
local IAng_ = mix( Begin, End, 0.0-1.0 )
```

***mix( v/a, v/a, n )*** is a linear-interpolation function that is (probably) most easily described as:

```php
function angle mix( Begin:angle, End:angle, Amount:number ){
    return Begin * Amount + End * (1 - Amount)
}
```

Problem is: The 3D angle range is -180 to 180, which is causing some glitching. (According to my friend it has to do with [Gimbal lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock).

I've tried a couple of things, which haven't worked due to the nature of the angles in Source Engine:

```php
function angle angle:to360(){
    local Absolute = ang( abs( This:pitch() ), abs( This:yaw() ), abs( This:roll() ) )
    local Pitch = This:pitch() < 0 ? Absolute:pitch() + 180 : Absolute:pitch()
    local Yaw = This:yaw() < 0 ? Absolute:yaw() + 180 : Absolute:yaw()   
    local Roll = This:roll() < 0 ? Absolute:roll() + 180 : Absolute:roll()

    return ang( Pitch, Yaw, Roll ) 
}
```

Or adding 180 to the angles.

**TL;DR** Interpolation of 3D angles facing the [Gimbal lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock) problem (angle range -180 to 180), best solution would be to have a function that converts to 0 **-** 360 range and back to -180 **-** 180.

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with Gimbal Lock. What glitching are you talking about? If done right, there should be no visual artifacts. Of course, Euler Angles aren't the best representation for interpolation. Hence, the result could look weird (but without artifacts). Show your actual interpolation code. Be sure to add/subtract only multiples of 360° to your angles. Adding/subtracting 180° changes the angle!

Comment: @NicoSchertler If an object's angle is [ 0, 0, 0 ] and I would rotate it right around a particular axis it will increase until 180, however, if I rotate it left it will go from -180 to 0 back to 180. The glitching is when the interpolation goes bazongas and decides to 360-flip the entity to close to what the angle was. It's like it goes over a certain line where the angle flips from positive to negative.

Comment: Euler angles are woefully unsuitable for doing any sort of geometric transformations on them. They are only useful for visual editing and as a redundancy-free representation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the `quat( angle )` function to convert the angles to a quaternion, I then used the slerp ( spherical linear interpolation ) function built in like so:

```php
local Ang = slerp( quat( Angle1 ), quat( Angle2 ), Interp ):toAngle()
```